# How do I install venom tox on ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, software-installation

Attempting to install venom using apt makes it possible for me to only start it if I am root.

Building from source gives the errors:

```
-- checking for module 'json-glib-1.0>=0.14'
--   package 'json-glib-1.0>=0.14' not found
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:266 (message):
  A required package was not found
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:320 (_pkg_check_modules_internal)
  cmake/PkgCheckModulesFullpath.cmake:21 (PKG_CHECK_MODULES)
  src/CMakeLists.txt:35 (PKG_CHECK_MODULES_FULLPATH)


-- checking for module 'libtoxcore>=0.0'
--   package 'libtoxcore>=0.0' not found
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:266 (message):
  A required package was not found
```

How do I install and use venom as a normal user?
Thank you

Comment: Do you have `libtoxcore>=0.0` installed?

Comment: [Venom has been discontinued](https://jenkins.libtoxcore.so/job/venom_win64/)